# Cómo pasar dependencias usando yield en FastAPI

Tags: python

Estoy utilizando FastApi y me gustaría saber si estoy utilizando correctamente las dependencias

Tengo una función para devolver la sesión de la base de datos:

```
class ContextManager:
     def __init__(self):
         self.db = DBSession()
  
     def __enter__(self):
         return self.db

     def __exit__(self):
         self.db.close()

def get_db():
         with ContextManager() as db:
          yield db
```

Después me gustaría utilizar esta dependencia en una función:

```
def validar(db=Depends(get_db)):

  is_valido = verificar(db)
  
  if not is valido:
     raise HTTPException(status_code=400)

  yield db
```

Y a su vez me gustaría utilizar esta función como dependencia en las rutas de la aplicación:

```
@router.get('/')
def get_datos(db=Depends(validar)):

  datos = db.query(...)

  return datos
```

Lo he probado y funciona pero me gustaría saber si esta es la forma idónea, sobre todo no tengo claro si está bien usar 'yield db' dentro de la función validar o debería usar un return.
Muchas gracias por adelantado